# Spring boot transaction cannot work in timer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a transaction like below,

```
@Transactional
public void changeJobStatus(Long jobId){
    JobEntity jobEntity = jobRepository.findOneForUpdate(jobId);
    ...
}
```

And findOneForUpdate is to lookup database with pessimistic lock,

```
public interface JobRepository extends CrudRepository<JobEntity, Long>{
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("select j from JobEntity j where j.id = :id")
    JobEntity findOneForUpdate(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

This works well, if I call **changeJobStatus** normally.

But when calling in a TimerTask like below,

```
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            changeJobStatus(jobId);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, waitTime);
```

there would be an exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Why this happens? And if there is a way to call transaction in a TimerTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `changeJobStatus()` is effectively direct to your bean (self-invocation), and therefore not subject to the usual Spring proxying when calling between beans. For this reason no transaction is getting started.

See:  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations search for "self-invocation".

There may be several potential ways to approach this:

1. You could auto-wire a reference to your own bean, which would be fulfilled with a proxy, and call thru that;
2. You could use mode="aspectj", which performs bytecode weaving (enhancement).
3. You could control the transaction manually via PlatformTransactionManager;

My approach would depend on whether this is isolated, or a common case. If common, I'd investigate "aspectj" mode; but I would probably hope that it were an outlier and I could stick to the standard Spring "proxy" mode.

Comment: tried this annotation @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ), but still not work.

Comment: Controlling transaction manually works, thank you! I have post an implementation below.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by Spring's AOP limitation. As Thomas has suggested, controlling transaction manually can solve this problem, rather than using @Transactional. Here is the detail implementation,

I have created an simple transaction service like below,

```
@Service
public class SimpleTransactionService {

    private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleTransactionService(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager){
        transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }

    public void executeTransaction(ITransactionService task){
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                task.transactionExecute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ITransactionService is just an simple interface with one method,

```
public interface ITransactionService {
    void transactionExecute();
}
```

Here is how I use above in my TimerTask,

```
public void addTimerTask(Object param, Long waitTime){
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            simpleTransactionService.executeTransaction(() -> someOperation(param));
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, waitTime);
}
```

**someOperation** is the actual transaction executed. With the simple transaction service and a lambda, transaction can be done without any annotation.